# Native ads not appearing in release build of android app

Tags: android, native-ads

I have integrated native ads in my android application, besides banner. I can see the banner ads and even interstitial ads in the released apk, but native ads appear as empty box. These ads however do appear in the debug apk. Not sure if proguard is doing something to the native ads. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I bet proguard. without a line of code all suggestions are guessing

Comment: sorry, its weird but it started appearing automatically after 2-3 hrs.

Comment: seems like server-side was causing this issue, not serving proper data. good to know it worked :)